# Using ajaxSend to capture requests from parent page within an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe

I have a web page that exists on my webserver (that I cannot modify) that sends ajax requests. Within that page is an iFrame which contains a page that I CAN change that exists within the same domain. From within that iFrame, I am trying to use ajaxSend to capture what the parent page is sending but it does not seem to be working. Is this possible to do from the iframe?

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).ajaxSend(function (evt, xhr, settings) {
            if (xhr != null) {
                $("#request").text(xhr);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks to jakecigar on the jQuery site for the response to this question.**

It would have to be in the exact same domain. You would have to navigate from the iframe to the parent

$( parent.document ).ajaxSend(…
should work.

JΛ̊KE